# combine two query , sum and max value of columns

Tags: php, mysql

I want to combine about 3 MySQL query to one , but some complex . (below is my test querys and table datas example)

**Table1: accounts**

```
id  |   account | email  | refer
11  |   aasdasd | 5@as.a | 0
12  |   gasd    | 4@ds.a | 11
13  |   xcsxs   | 3@ss.a | 11
14  |   cbasd   | 2@as.a | 11
15  |   asdv    | 1@gs.a | 11
16  |   sdfgx   | 6@hs.a | 8
```

...

**Table2: characters**

```
guid    |account| name | rank   | time
561     |   11  | asda | 945    | 12
562     |   11  | asda | 746    | 19
563     |   11  | asda | 452    | 1
564     |   12  | asda | 123    | 15
565     |   12  | asda | 456    | 18
566     |   13  | asda | 123    | 6
567     |   13  | asda | 789    | 18
568     |   13  | asda | 123    | 17
569     |   15  | asda | 456    | 13
570     |   16  | asda | 123    | 15
571     |   17  | asda | 456    | 16
```

...
**My Tested Querys**:

```
 SELECT id FROM accounts WHERE refer='11'
```

to identify the accounts was refer with value '11'
and second query to show and sum totaltime of accounts characters where was have refer with value 11 :

```
SELECT a.account, a.email, SUM(c.time) , c.rank
FROM accounts a, characters c
WHERE a.id=c.account
ORDER BY MAX(c.rank) DESC
```

**Whats i want:**
I want to combine the above two query two one and have a result like below :
rank column is highest rank of character from account and totaltime is sum of all characters time of that account

```
Account | Email | Rank | TotalTime
gasd    |4@ds.a | 456  | 33
xcsxs   |3@ss.a | 789  | 41
cbasd   |2@as.a |  0   | 0
asdv    |1@gs.a | 456  | 13
```

second query with SUM I think have problem , I add it now .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
    SELECT a.account, a.email,  c.rank,SUM(c.time) totaltime
    FROM accounts a
    INNER JOIN characters c
    ON a.id = c.account

    WHERE a.refer=11
    ORDER BY MAX(c.rank) DESC
```

edit :

```
   SELECT a.account, a.email,  MAX(c.rank) rank,SUM(c.time) totaltime
    FROM accounts a
     left JOIN characters c
    ON a.id = c.account

    WHERE a.refer=11
  group by a.account
   ORDER BY MAX(c.rank) DESC
```

[**LOOK DEMO SQLFIDDLE**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4fb76/6)

Comment: group was missing ... thanks it' work ;) .... `EDIT:` record of fast answer :D thanks ;)